# JSON format for treemap

Tags: d3.js

I have (or will have) a treemap which uses d3.json to fetch its data.
I am getting an error "Error: no root".

I suspect this is due to not having the correct format for the JSON data.

or possibble, where I assign the data.. or both?

```
       var dc = data.company
    d = {};
    d.id = +dc.id
    d.value1 = +dc.value1
    d.value2 = +dc.value2
```

plnkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/EAkkNH4iGrRmhvDCi5Jr?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

So the issue was both the json and the way in which it was referenced.

Working code:
https://plnkr.co/edit/dWzTNtXCkWapmfc5UBG4?p=preview

In the code itself the data needed to be created within the main function

```
var d = {};
d.id = data[count].id
d.value1 = data[count].value1
d.value2 = data[count].value2
```

Whilst in the json data, the root element was missing, so unable to create child nodes. See the plunkr data.json file for the working format required for the chart to work.

Comment: If you have found a solution, instead of redirecting users to the link, it will be nice to show what changes you have made to the problematic section of code in the answer itself.